# Discrepancy between gettimeofday() and times()

Tags: linux, performance, time

I'm doing some performance analysis of a large application. We have some performance tracing functions that I'm using. One of them uses [times()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html) and the sum of all fields to get cumulative CPU time and [gettimeofday()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) to get elapsed time.

For the part of the application that I'm analyzing there is a big discrepancy between the two. I'm seeing a cumulative CPU time from `times()` of around 17700 seconds but an elapsed time from `gettimeofday()` of 51000 seconds.

The only thing that I can think of is that this could be related to swap or NUMA issues. The peak memory consumption occurs during the section where I see the time discrepancy. The app reaches about 470Gbytes according to `rusage`, on a 20 core/512Gbyte server with no other jobs running.

Does `times()` only report the time spent running on the CPU, or does it also include the time spent uninterruptible?

I've seen that `/usr/bin/times -v` gives some interesting output. Are there any other options for monitoring either the app or the OS? I'm also thinking of running vmstat the next time that I run a test to try to follow how much paging is happening.

EDIT:
[`perf stat`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) looks interesting. I will update with results as I get them.

Comment: `perf stat` would give you another interesting data point.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll try that on my next run.

Comment: `gettimeofday()` is not monotic and can change e.g. by `ntp` or manual time changes.  Better use `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: Can you figure out which time is "off" based on first principles? The numbers are very large, hours of CPU time - so based on how long (wall clock) you observe the run to take, plus the expected number of CPUs used, does the `gettimeofday` or the `clock` result seem more in line with what you'd expect? Remember that if you have more threads than cores, this is entirely expected: the `times()` will only return the time the current thread was actually running, while `getttimeofday()` will include all time since the last read including times _other_ threads were running.

Comment: @ensc I can't easily change that code. In this case I doubt that clock variations are the cause.

Comment: @BeeOnRope the `gettimeofday()` value seems to be correct. The section of code that I'm analyzing is single process, single thread (at least afaik).